# Get itemprop with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to parse three itemprop tags like this:

```html
<span itemprop="actors" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<a href="/name/nm0005417?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm" itemprop="url"><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Lin Shaye</span></a>,             </span>
<span itemprop="actors" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<a href="/name/nm1191481?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm" itemprop="url"><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Leigh Whannell</span></a>,             </span>
<span itemprop="actors" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<a href="/name/nm0760151?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm" itemprop="url"><span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Angus Sampson</span></a>            </span>
```

and I use python code:

```
soup.find('span',itemprop="actors")
```

but I only get first itemprop tag. How can i get all three itemprop tags. thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) before asking a question on SO. Do some research. The first thing you get is the `find_all()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `soup.find(...)` use `soup.find_all(...)`

For example, if you want the names:

```
for span in soup.find_all('span',itemprop="actors"):
    print(span.string) # Prints names
```

Or, to save names in a list:

```
names = [span.string for span in soup.find_all(...)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use:

```
  for actor in soup.find_all(attrs={'itemprop': 'actors' }):
     print(actor.text.strip())
```